# Python: Is order preserved when iterating a tuple?

Tags: python, loops, tuples

In Python, if I run the code:

```
T=('A','B','C','D')
D={}
i=0
for item in T:
    D[i]=item
    i=i+1
```

Can I be sure that D will be organized as:

```
D = {0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C', 3:'D'}
```

I know that tuples' order cannot be changed because they are immutable, but am I *guaranteed* that it will always be iterated in order as well?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed that the tuple will be iterated over in that order. *Dictionaries* however are unordered, so you *can't* rely on their order (the `key:value` mapping will be guaranteed to be the way you showed it though). Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you need an order preserving dictionary.

Comment: @LukasGraf [Changed in version 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict): Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, tuples are ordered and iteration follows that order. Guaranteed™.

You can generate your `D` in one expression with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to produce the indices:

```
D = dict(enumerate(T))
```

That's because `enumerate()` produces `(index, value)` tuples, and `dict()` accepts a sequence of `(key, value)` tuples to produce the dictionary:

```
>>> T = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
>>> dict(enumerate(T))
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}
```

Comment: And now I see that I can use enumerate(T,start) to begin my indices with some offset. I'm reading blocks of memory from an embedded device and I want to map it into a dictionary whose keys are the memory addresses from the embedded device. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @gabroncancio: your link is nice, but doesn't actually *document the iteration behaviour*. I had not added the link myself for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since **tuples** are sequences (due to *The standard type hierarchy*) and are ordered by [implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), it has the `__iter__()` method to comply with the *Iterator protocol* which means that each `next` value of the `tuple` just yielded in the same ordered fashion because point the same object.